# RSPEC fails, doesn't initialize factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

In my app, `project` `has_many` `another_project`.
I have the following test:

```
describe 'some test' do
    let(:project) { create(:live_project) }
    let(:another_project) { create(:another_project, :project => project ) }

    # before do
    #  another_project
    # end

    it 'does something' do
        expect ...
    end
end
```

It fails unless the commented code runs.

This seems strange because the line with `another_project` doesn't do anything. It seems as if the factory isn't properly initialized until something points to it.

What could be the issue that makes it fail/work with/without those commented lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems as if the factory isn't being properly initialised until something points to it.

That's a feature. Lazy initialization, it's called. If a thing is not used, why do the work of creating it?

Either use a `let!` instead of `let`, for things you want to always be created. Or create them in a `before` block.